# Why is a condition in a for-loop initialisation faster than inside the loop?

Tags: c#, optimization

I'm doing a bit of optimization and found out that this:

```
for (int x = -1; x < 2; x++)
{
    for (int y = -1; y < 2 ; y++)
    {
        if (((x * x) ^ (y * y)) != 1)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

takes more than twice as long to run as this:

```
for (int x = -1; x < 2; x++)
{
    for (int y = -1; y < 2 && ((x * x) ^ (y * y)) == 1; y++)
    {

    }
}
```

What is going on here?

The purpose is avoiding diagonal(-1,-1; -1,1 ...) and the origin(0,0) fields

Comment: how did you test it?

Comment: @Steve ran both versions 100million times 10 times in a row. Debug mode

Comment: Timing tests are best done using release builds with optimizations on, and not using the debugger, since in the end that's what matters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The second code ends the inner loop when `((x * x) ^ (y * y)) != 1`, whereas the first code only skips one iteration of the inner loop.  Since they don't do the same thing, all bets are off on comparing performance.